# Adjust width of horizontal table on LaTeX

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, longtable, page-numbering, page

I am trying to create a long table and doing it horizontally. I want to adjust the table so it fits with the page (horizontally). It is currently like this:

[image]

I would like to make it look like this:

[image]

Also, is there anyway (as the 2nd picture shows) have the page number in that position (with centring). Note this table lasts many pages, here's the code:

```
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{pdflscape} 

\begin{landscape}
\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{*{8}{|c|} }
\hline
Item Number & Item Description & Quantity & Capacity & Operating             
Conditions & Design Conditions & Construction Materials & Special         
Requirements \\ 
\hline
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & 8147.6 m\textsuperscript{3} & 25         
bar, 25°C & 31.25 bar, 31.25°C & Steel & Spherical \\ 
\hline
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank& 1 & 37728.7 m\textsuperscript{3} & 25 
bar, 25°C & 31.25 bar, 31.25°C & Steel & Spherical\\ 
\hline
...
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: welcome to tex.!se (**i**) search for similar questions and see how there is solved the very same problems (**ii**) investigate if writing column headers in two column helps (by narrowing of columns) (**iii**)  use `\multirow` wherever the same data in the column follows (with content divided into several lines), (**iv**) don't use vertical lines, (**v**) use rules from `booktabs` for horizontal lines (**vi**) for values with units use `siunitx` package (**vii**) consider `threeparttable`/`threeparttablex` for use `\tnote` and `tablenotes` for notes in table, etc ...

Comment: Hi, in general you can resize and center all content using the `adjustbox` package. However, `longtable` will want to break the content over multiple pages, so there should be issues.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex, makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{4}{c|} *{4}{X|} }% in case that you like to havew centered cells' content, use "C" instead of "X"
\hline
\thead{Item\\ Number}
    & \thead{Item\\ Description}
        & \thead{Quantity}
            & \thead{Capacity}
                & \thead{Operating\\ Conditions}
                    & \thead{Design\\ Conditions}
                        & \thead{Construction\\ Materials}
                            & \thead{Special\\ Requirements} \\
\endfirsthead
\hline
\thead{Item\\ Number}
    & \thead{Item\\ Description}
        & \thead{Quantity}
            & \thead{Capacity}
                & \thead{Operating\\ Conditions}
                    & \thead{Design\\ Conditions}
                        & \thead{Construction\\ Materials}
                            & \thead{Special\\ Requirements} \\
\endhead
    \hline
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{8147.6}{\metre\cubic}  & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
    \hline
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{37728.7}{\metre\cubic} & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
\hline
... &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

the package `ltablex` combine `longtable` and `tabularx`. for units i suggest to use `siunitx`. for column header is used macro `\thead` from the package `makecell`

[image]

i wouldn't use vertical lines and use of horizontal ones reduced to minimum. instead `\hline` i would rather use rules from the package `booktabs` (`\toprule`, `midrule`, `bottomrule` and after each fit rows insert `\addlinespace`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, ltablex, makecell}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\footnotesize
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                        *{4}{c} 
                        *{4}{X} }
    \toprule
\thead{Item\\ Number}
    & \thead{Item\\ Description}
        & \thead{Quantity}
            & \thead{Capacity}
                & \thead{Operating\\ Conditions}
                    & \thead{Design\\ Conditions}
                        & \thead{Construction\\ Materials}
                            & \thead{Special\\ Requirements} \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
\thead{Item\\ Number}
    & \thead{Item\\ Description}
        & \thead{Quantity}
            & \thead{Capacity}
                & \thead{Operating\\ Conditions}
                    & \thead{Design\\ Conditions}
                        & \thead{Construction\\ Materials}
                            & \thead{Special\\ Requirements} \\
    \midrule
\endhead
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{8147.6}{\metre\cubic}  & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{37728.7}{\metre\cubic} & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{8147.6}{\metre\cubic}  & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{37728.7}{\metre\cubic} & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{8147.6}{\metre\cubic}  & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
    \addlinespace
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{37728.7}{\metre\cubic} & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-100 & Feed 1 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{8147.6}{\metre\cubic}  & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
TK-101 & Feed 2 Storage Tank & 1 & \SI{37728.7}{\metre\cubic} & \SI{25}{\bar}, \SI{25}{\celsius} & \SI{31.25}{\bar}, \SI{31.25}{\celsius} & Steel & Spherical \\
... &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```